# identify queries experiencing sos_scheduler_yield

Tags: sql-server-2014

Is there a way to capture the queries experiencing the SOS_Scheduler_Yield wait type as it is happening.  My cpu is pegging out at night and I suspect its some xml processing that is causing it by chewing up all my processor cycles; however, the application design is such that what is coming back as having the highest worker time is a section of xml that should only be run one time per client.  So I need to catch the individual offending query each night to make my case.

Comment: Have you considered XEvents trace or persist WhoIsActive into a table? Run it during the troubled times and then analyze the output.

Comment: @DenisT - Sorry not overly familiar with extended events but I can look into setting that up.

Comment: are you familiar with sp_WhoIsActive -- http://whoisactive.com/? It's super easy to set up to collect data into a table for a period of time every whatever seconds. It's super lightweight as well.

Answer (score 2):

The Extended Events option is by far the easiest solutions, once you get used to Extended Events.

### Explanation

An article on SQLPerformance.com goes into the specifics behind this wait type...

> ...
>   So there is one cause for SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD: a thread exhausting its scheduling quantum and heavily recurring instances can lead to SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD being the most prevalent wait along with high CPU usage.
>   ...
>   The only way to prove what's causing SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD waits is to capture SQL Server call stacks when that wait type occurs, using Extended Events and debug symbols from Microsoft. I have a [blog post](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sos_scheduler_yield-waits-and-the-lock_hash-spinlock/) that describes and shows how to perform that investigation, and there’s a great whitepaper about spinlocks and spinlock investigations that is worth reading if you’re interested in that depth of internals.

***Reference:*** [Knee-Jerk Wait Statistics : SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/02/sql-performance/knee-jerk-waits-sos-scheduler-yield)

It also relates to how you can perform an analysis (blog in above quote):

***Reference:*** [SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD waits and the LOCK_HASH spinlock](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sos_scheduler_yield-waits-and-the-lock_hash-spinlock/) (SQLSkills.com)

### Extended Events

Add an Extended Event to your instance with the following code:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Capture_Statements_SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlos.wait_info(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.sql_text)
    WHERE ([wait_type]=(123))) 
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'C:\Temp\Capture_Statements_SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD.xel')
WITH (STARTUP_STATE=ON)
GO
```

> **Caution**
>   Check the `filename` and modify to your preference!
>   Check the `STARTUP_STATE`!
>   Modify the Extended Event to your preferences when finished.

***Reference:*** [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events) (Microsoft Docs)

### Quick solution

A quick solution is to just run the following script when you are having issues:

```
SELECT sdow.session_id,
       sdow.wait_type,
       sder.status,
       sder.sql_handle,
       DB_NAME(sder.database_id),
       dest.text
FROM   sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks    AS sdow
       JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests  AS sder
            ON  sdow.session_id = sder.session_id
       CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sder.sql_handle) AS dest
WHERE  sdow.wait_type = 'SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD'
```

### References

- [Knee-Jerk Wait Statistics : SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/02/sql-performance/knee-jerk-waits-sos-scheduler-yield) (SQLPerformance.com)
- [SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD waits and the LOCK_HASH spinlock](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sos_scheduler_yield-waits-and-the-lock_hash-spinlock/) (SQLSkills.com)
- [sys.dm_exec_requests (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql) (Microsoft Docs)
- [sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-waiting-tasks-transact-sql) (Microsoft Docs)
- [sys.dm_exec_sql_text (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sql-text-transact-sql) (Microsoft Docs)
- [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events) (Microsoft Docs)